# Atribuir retorno de findOne para uma variavel global node Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Nao consegui fazer essa atribuição, sera que falta algo?

```
 global.pedido = db.collection('configuracoes').findOne({ parametro: "pedido_num"})
```

Comment: Nesse collection eu tenho {parametro:"pedido_num",valor:100}

Comment: no console fica assim:Pedido numero: [object Promise]
{ numero: Promise { <pending> },
  pacote: 'Pacote Gold',
  cupom: '',
  desconto: 0,

Comment: fiz uma edicao segundo o manual do mongodb, mas nao adiantou. global.pedido = db.collection('configuracoes').findOne({ parametro: "pedido_num"},{valor:1});

Answer (score 1):

`findOne` retorna uma *Promise*, portanto o resultado só estará pronto quando a ela for resolvida. Pode-se usado o resultado dessa forma:

```
db.collection('configuracoes').findOne({ parametro: "pedido_num"}, function(err, document) {
  if ( !err ) global.pedido = document;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar colocar em uma função de callback destinada a encontrar algum erro, caso exista. Por exemplo:

```
try {
  global.pedido = db.collection('configuracoes').findOne({ parametro: "pedido_num"});
} catch (error) {
console.log('>>>>>> Error: ', error);
}
```

Comment: Matheus, testei não dá erro, mas fica a questão do promise e não retorna o valor

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de obter o resultado da `Promise` é utilizando `await`, porém é preciso que este comando esteja dentro de uma função assíncrona (basta marcá-la como `async`).

```js
try {
    global.pedido = await db.collection('configuracoes').findOne({ parametro: "pedido_num"});
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```